# 'get_call' was not declared in this scope in C++

Tags: c++, vector, eclipse-cdt

This is my first time working with C++.. And I have setup eclipse CDT environment in my windows machine... And I wrote below code but somehow, it is giving me an error on get_call method like this -

```
'get_call' was not declared in this scope
```

Below is my code -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    vector<string> data;
    data.push_back("0");
    data.push_back("1");
    data.push_back("2");

    get_call("1234", data);

    return 0;
}

void get_call(string id, vector<string> data) {

    for(std::vector<T>::reverse_iterator it = data.rbegin(); it != data.rend(); ++it) {
        std::cout << *it;
    }
}
```

Is there anything wrong I am doing in my above code?

I am working with eclipse CDT on windows?

And my next question is - In general what's the best way to work with C++? Should I use Ubuntu VM in VMWARE Player to compile c++ project as I am finding very hard time making it work in eclipse CDT..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to forward declare `get_call` function before call it. **In C++ a symbol needs to be known before it's used.**

```
void get_call(string id, vector<string> data);  // forward declare get_call function

int main() {

    vector<string> data;
    data.push_back("0");
    data.push_back("1");
    data.push_back("2");

    get_call("1234", data);

    return 0;
}

// function definition
void get_call(string id, vector<string> data) {

    for(std::vector<string>::reverse_iterator it = data.rbegin();  // should be vector<strign>
        it != data.rend(); ++it) {
        std::cout << *it;
    }
}
```

You wrote `std::vector<T>::reverse_iterator` as compiler has no idea what `T` is, you should use `vector<string>`

Comment: Thanks blitz for the suggestion.. Yes that error is gone now but I am getting an error on the for loop now as `expected ';' before ')' token` Is there anything wrong I am doing in my for loop?

Comment: should be vector<string>

Answer (score 0):

Put the get_call() before the main(), or forward declare get_call(). Since you are working on Windows, visual studio(VC++ express is free) is fine, or cygwin if you want to run your code on Linux without a Linux OS, and of course working in VMWARE Player makes you program in a nearly real Linux OS.